# Inequality in combinatorial sum of products of vector elements

Tags: inequality, vector-spaces, permutations

For $n > 2$, let $x, y \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that

- $x_1 \leq x_2 \leq \cdots \leq x_n$
- $\|x\|=\|y\|=1$
- $x \cdot y = \sum_i x_i = \sum_i y_i = 0$

Can we prove that $\displaystyle{\sum_{i < j \,:\, y_i > y_j}}(x_i y_j + x_j y_i) \geq 1/4$?

---

Numerical tests suggest that this is true, and it's also equivalent to some other open inequalities I've seen, but I didn't manage to prove it.